# Preserving Newline In Input Received From raw_input

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've created a script that allows me to send emails from the command line. The script works fine; however, I'd like to be able to add newline characters ('\n') in the body of the email. The raw_input function is putting the '\n' as literal input. How do I get around this?

Example:

```
body = raw_input('Enter your message: ')

>>>Enter your message: This\nShould\nbe\non\n6\nlines
>>>print(body)
'This\nShould\nbe\non\n6\nlines'
```

I would like it to show:

```
>>>Enter your message: This\nShould\nbe\non\n6\nlines
>>>print(body)
'This
Should
be
on
6
lines'
```

Comment: How about `body.split('\n')`?

Comment: Escape sequences are only processed in string literals in source code, not in input. If you need them to be interpreted, you need to write your own code to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing to "preserve", because `raw_input()` reads literal input, it doesn't interpret escape sequences. If you want `\n` to be treated as newline, you have to do it yourself:

```
body = body.replace(r'\n', '\n')
```